# Button to open a different visual force page opens a blank / broken page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a visual force page and a button called that is supposed to take the user to another visual force page.

A problem however is this page is completely blank or just isn't loading it seems.

UDCallout.vfp

```
   <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%"><apex:commandButton action="{!createQuote}" value="Create Quote" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Apex Controller

```
public PageReference createQuote()
{
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/UDQuote');
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
```

UDQuote.vfp

```
<apex:page>
    hello world
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you try instead of `PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/UDQuote');` the following line: `PageReference pr = Page.UDQuote;` ?

Answer (score 2):

This should be sufficient and avoids typos in the page name and to ensure that the page is present:

```
public PageReference createQuote()
{
    return Page.UDQuote;
}
```

though you would get the error of "Page UDQuote does not exist" if it wasn't.

I'd update the text in the page to be sure something is there in case a blank version of the page is in the org.

**PS**

In response to the comment question about adding parameters, the expression `Page.UDQuote` is really a factory method that creates a new `PageReference` instance so you can pass parameters like this:

```
public PageReference createQuote()
{
    PageReference pr = Page.UDQuote;
    pr.getParameters().put('myKey', 'myValue');
    return pr;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to also pass a parameter to that page or its own apex controller, for example an Id or list?

Comment: @AlexanderAtkinsoon See the PS.